# Mismatch of data type when passing argument

Tags: c++, excel, vba, types

I am currently facing following problem. I have searched for any solution but could not find anything useful related to my problem.

I want to use VBA to provide some parameters to a self-written DLL which is going to calculate a result for me.

My problem: As soon as I try to process the values passed to the function **setCEPCI** I get an "Microsoft Excel has stopped working"- error(no further details). If I put those three lines (see my copied code) in comments, however, everything is working fine. I tried a lot of workarounds but it all came down to those lines.
Surprisingly, I can use the passed arguments in the first function **getPEC**, where e.g. **x** is my **outflow**.

For the record I am using a def file for exporting the function, though, IMHO the error seems to be some mismatch of data types.

**EDIT: For clarification: If my DLL is not found e.g. I get the same Microsoft-Excel-error due to the RV assignment. If I try to assign any value to RV in the first function, I also get that error. On the other hand I can assign any value to PEC without problems.**

My DLL looks like:

```
extern "C" {



typedef void(CALLBACK * FncPtrClssGetCEPCI)(CEPCIvalues &, int, int, int &);

double PEC_backUp;
const int numbMaxCEPCIlistMembers = 3;
CEPCIvalues cepcilist_backUp[numbMaxCEPCIlistMembers];

void __stdcall getPEC(int typeOfPump, double outflow, double &PEC, int &RV)
{
    //y = a x^6 + b x^5 + c x^4 + d x^3 + e x^2 + f x^1 + g x^0
    if ((typeOfPump < 1) || (10 < typeOfPump)) {
        RV = -1;
        return;
    }
    double a, b, c, d, e, f, g;
//...
    PEC_backUp = a * pow(outflow, 6.0) +
        b * pow(outflow, 5.0) +
        c * pow(outflow, 4.0) +
        d * pow(outflow, 3.0) +
        e * pow(outflow, 2.0) +
        f * pow(outflow, 1.0) +
        g * pow(outflow, 0.0);


    double EUR_USD_07_2000 = 0.939082609;
    PEC_backUp = PEC_backUp / EUR_USD_07_2000;
    PEC = PEC_backUp;
}

void __stdcall setCEPCI(int monthIN, int yearIN, int &RV)
{
    //HINSTANCE hinstCEPCI = LoadLibraryEx("CEPCI.dll", NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_APPLICATION_DIR);
    HINSTANCE hinstCEPCI = LoadLibrary("C:\\Users\\...somePath...\\CEPCI.dll");
    if (!hinstCEPCI)
    {
        RV = -11;
        return;
    }
    FncPtrClssGetCEPCI ptrGetCEPCI = (FncPtrClssGetCEPCI)GetProcAddress(hinstCEPCI, "getCEPCI");
    if (!ptrGetCEPCI)
    {
        RV = -22;
        return;
    }
    //CEPCI values of 13/1970 and 07/2000 are automatically extracted
    //due to less interaction and, thus, risk of errors in user input

    int monthIN_auto = 13;
    int yearIN_auto = 1970;
    ptrGetCEPCI(cepcilist_backUp[0], monthIN_auto, yearIN_auto, RV);
    monthIN_auto = 7;
    yearIN_auto = 2000;
    ptrGetCEPCI(cepcilist_backUp[1], monthIN_auto, yearIN_auto, RV);
    //now extract CEPCI value of user specific input




  //  monthIN_auto = monthIN;

  //  yearIN_auto = yearIN;


    ptrGetCEPCI(cepcilist_backUp[2], monthIN_auto, yearIN_auto, RV);
        CEPCIvalues cepcilist;
        cepcilist = cepcilist_backUp[2];





// RV = monthIN + yearIN;

    ptrGetCEPCI = 0;
    FreeLibrary(hinstCEPCI);
    hinstCEPCI = 0;
    return;
}
```

My VBA code looks like:

```
Public Declare Sub getPEC _
Lib "C:\Users\...somePath...\OPunit0011PUMP.dll" _
(ByVal typeOfPump As Integer, ByVal outflow As Double, ByRef PEC As Double, ByRef RV As Integer)

Public Declare Sub setCEPCI _
Lib "C:\Users\...somePath...\OPunit0011PUMP.dll" _
(ByVal monthIN As Integer, ByVal yearIN As Integer, ByRef RV As Integer)


Function CallPump()

Dim typeOfPump, RV, monthIN, yearIN As Integer
typeOfPump = 9
Dim outlfow, PEC As Double
outflow = 100
monthIN = 5
yearIN = 2008

Call getPEC(typeOfPump, outflow, PEC, RV)

Call setCEPCI(monthIN, yearIN, RV)




End Function
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried changing the Declare to ...Declare PtrSafe Sub. The Prtsafe is required for VBA7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved my problem.

Looking at the VBA code

```
Dim typeOfPump, RV, monthIN, yearIN as Integer
```

for any reason declared only typeOfPump as integer, the rest were (when monitoring with implemented watching function of Excel) still variant. Writing

```
Dim typeOfPump as Integer
Dim RV as Integer
...
```

seems to solve the problem. Unfortunately, I cannot explain what is wrong with the first line.

Comment: Its a foible of VBA. Only the first Dim is set as the datatype if you separate other items with commas. The other items become variants.

Comment: I was explicitly looking for that before. See here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee5a7s1.aspx
**Declaring Multiple Variables
You can declare several variables in one declaration statement, specifying the variable name for each one, and following each array name with parentheses. Multiple variables are separated by commas.**
That seems odd to me.

Comment: That refers to Visual Basic. Excel VBA is more of a Visual Basic Lite!